# Remove quote character " from my strings before Posting to mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code to insert Event Logs and User Info from my Mobile App to a mysql database.

I am finding the `"` Character gives me issues later on when in use with JSON arrays that I pull from the db.  What I would like to do is remove the `"` character in the php code completely before posting to the db.

Removing the `"` character by Javascript from the Mobile App is not really an option.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "Fred";
$password = "Barney";
$dbname = "BamBam";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    // escape variables for security
    $event_log = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_log']);
    $logged_by = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['logged_by']);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO time_event (event_log, logged_by)
    VALUES ('$event_log', '$logged_by')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "Data entered successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: encode it properly, then you don't need to remove it

Comment: Maybe use pdo, it will encode for you

Comment: "*gives me issues latter on*"—please elaborate.

Comment: Why not use `addslashes()` on input or `stripslashes()` on output? If it's sensitive data use MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT()`, storing your data in a `BLOB` datatype.

Comment: Dagon,  I think encoding is the issue, with this mysql_real_escape_string not working as it should.  Could you point me in the right direction on properly encoding this Insert.  PHP Admin info shared server-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 3.5.3
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Server version: 5.5.39-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.32-pl0-gentoo

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mysqli_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [`mysqli_stmt_bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to execute a *parameterised query*.  I strongly advise this approach.

If you really want to just escape special characters for manual interpolation
into a query string, use [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Hand-rolling a solution presents a real risk that you will
miss something important, leaving your program vulnerable
to [*SQL injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: I found that using the mysqli::real_escape_string  and str_replace escaped my problem children and the str_replace removed totally the " charter.  Thanks fraserweedale

Comment: This is what it looked like.  
 $logged_by1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,  $event_log1 = str_replace('"','',$event_log1);
 $logged_by1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['logged_by1']);

Answer (score 0):

I did not try, but this should do

```
 $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO time_event (event_log, logged_by)
VALUES ('%s' ,'%s'",$event_log,$logged_by);
```